# Pasting into JTable skips the last of selected cells

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a Java Swing app that contains a JTable with several columns and rows. I want to enable the possibility to select several cells in a single column, copy them and paste them in another selected group of cells.

I found a tip online to use ExcelAdapter class ([here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077579/learn-java/java-tip-77--enable-copy-and-paste-functionality-between-swing-s-jtables-and-excel.html)). I created my own class based on that example, a bit simpler I believe as I don't need to check if only adjacent cells are selected or if the selected cells are in more than one column (this is disabled in my app).

It does work to some extent but not exactly as I would like. I can select cells and copy them to clipboard. I can also paste them but for some reason the last cell in selected pasting area is skipped (i.e. not pasted into). If the amount of selected copied cells is the same as selected amount of pasting area cells, the amount of pasted cells is selected pasting area cells - 1. If there are more cells copied (e.g. 4 cells) and less cells selected to be pasted into (e.g. 2), the last cell selected for pasting is skipped and pasting continues from one cell below.

Below is the code of my version of ExcelAdapter class:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class CopyPasteMachine {

private JTable table;
private Clipboard clipboard;
private StringSelection transferableString;
private String stringValue;
KeyStroke copy;
KeyStroke paste;

public CopyPasteMachine (JTable t) {

    table = t;
    clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

    if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("mac")) {
        copy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask(), false);
        paste = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask(), false);
    } else {
        copy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK, false);
        paste = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK, false);
    }

    table.getInputMap().put(copy, "copy");
    table.getActionMap().put("copy", new AbstractAction() {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7400399952613035707L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            int rowCount = table.getSelectedRowCount();
            int [] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
            int columnNo = table.getSelectedColumn();

            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
                stringBuffer.append(table.getValueAt(rows[i], columnNo));
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
                }
            transferableString = new StringSelection(stringBuffer.toString());
            clipboard.setContents(transferableString, transferableString);
        }
    });

    table.getInputMap().put(paste, "paste");
    table.getActionMap().put("paste", new AbstractAction() {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 3678654129316517021L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int startRow = (table.getSelectedRows())[0];
            int columnNo = table.getSelectedColumn();

            try {
                String tempStringValue = (String)(clipboard.getContents(this).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(tempStringValue,"\n");
                for (int i = 0; tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
                    stringValue = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    if (startRow + i < table.getRowCount()) {
                            table.setValueAt(stringValue, startRow + i, columnNo);
                   }
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e1) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong");
                System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong");
                System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public JTable getTable() {
    return table;
}

public void setTable(JTable table) {
    this.table = table;
}
}
```

Comment: Is data in the clipboard OK?

Comment: Yes, pasting to notepad or just looking up what was copied reveals that all selected cells were copied. Problem appears only when pasting into selected cells.